# Do devices need to be registered with the provisioning portal to install an Enterprise app onto them?

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I have an Enterprise account and have registered one device with the Apple Provisioning portal  and included it into the distribution portal, and can install the app onto that device as expected.

I am experimenting with installing the app onto a device which I have not registered with the portal and am unable to. However I was under the impression that it was possible to install Enterprise apps onto devices without having to add them to the portal and profile as is the case with standard ad-hoc builds.

Am I therefore mistaken? If I am mistaken then when I logon to Apple account it says there is a limit of 100 devices despite it being an Enterprise account not a regular developer account.
So why is that?

If it is possible to install an Enterprise app onto a device which has not been added to the provisioning portal then how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're signing the application with the distribution certificate, not the development certificate.